# How do I upload large (30MB) files via a web interface?

Tags: iis, php, php.ini, upload

Because I'm stumped...

The client needs to be able to upload large images to a library but the upload fails after 5-6MB (over my poor connection).  It seems to be timing out as the filesize at fail isn't consistent.

The setup is a form which is accepted by PHP.  I've googled and played with php.ini and everything is set for big uploads and long timeouts.  Platform is a dedicated windows server at GoDaddy.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure these two settings in PHP are set:

- **upload_max_filesize** - should be a little larger then the biggest file you expect
- **post_max_size** - this needs to be larger then upload_max_filesize

Comment: Been there, done that.  They're both set to 80MB so I don't think that's the problem.  Also, if I was running up against an upload limit I'd expect it to fail at the same number of bytes each time.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

After TWO YEARS of on-and-off wrestling with this server I discovered that the app pool was set to time out at 5 minutes.  Now I get a 500 error when the file finishes but I'm better equipped to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

Dpeending on what version of windows you are running (IIS 7), you may also need to adjust the request filtering module.

By default it cuts off at 5 MB or so.  To change open an administrative command prompt:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set config -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:1048576
```

The size is in bytes.

Comment: Sounds good, I'm going to try that tonight.